# Display user picture below content type article

Tags: 7, theming, panels

How can i display user name and picture below node article.
My theme is based on panels so i dont know where to write code for it. Or any admin option.

Thanks

Comment: You want to display the node's author information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module that comes with the Ctools module called Views Content Panes. Enable that. Also a good idea to enable the Context module, can be fetched here: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/context

Views Content Panes is used to output Views as panel panes.

Import code for a View that will be a good starting point for your solution is provided at the end of this answer. This view will display the Article's author username and picture.

You may need to edit the "Argument input" setting in the view.

[image]

I set it to use the "From context" option, and the required context of Author.

This has a good chance of working immediately, but we may need to go further into your panels configuration if it doesn't.

After enabling the Views Content Pane module, and importing and saving the view, you will be able to add the newly created pane to your panel.

[image]

Import this view code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_name_and_pic_for_articles';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'User Name and Pic for Articles';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Picture */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['id'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['field'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['link_photo_to_profile'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'not found';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Username and Pic for Articles Content pane */
$handler = $view->new_display('panel_pane', 'Username and Pic for Articles Content pane', 'panel_pane_1');
$handler->display->display_options['argument_input'] = array(
  'uid' => array(
    'type' => 'context',
    'context' => 'entity:node.author',
    'context_optional' => 0,
    'panel' => '0',
    'fixed' => '',
    'label' => 'Author: Uid',
  ),
);
```

Comment: I did it with EVA Field

Comment: But that also included steps you have mentioned above. Thanks alot.

Comment: I've use EVA many times, I only chose Views Content Panes for the answer because you are using Panels. Good choice! EVA is super cool.